# Como agregar botón a un hover en una imagen snip ?? Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Hola quisiera saber como puedo agregar un botón VER VIDEO como el de la imagen adjunta y que aparezca solamente cuando paso el mouse sobre la imagen.

```js
  $(".hover").mouseleave(
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
  );
```

```css
/************************************************************************************/
/*********************************ULTIMAS NOVEDADES****************************/
/***********************************************************************************/

#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 {
    font-family: 'stainlesscond-lightregular';
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 236px;
  max-width: 359px;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 307px;

}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .image {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  height: 100%;
  width: 489px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% 0;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 figcaption {
  top: 88%;
  left: 20px;
  right: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 figcaption h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 i {
  background-color: #e41c14;
  top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 25px;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .icon {
  background-color: #e41c14;
  top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 25px;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date .month {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 i {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 52px;
    padding: 20px;

}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 h3,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover img,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover .date {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover i,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover i {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover .icon,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover .icon {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}


#inicio .contenido-novedades figure .recuadro{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 307px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure .recuadro p{
  top: 40%;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'stainlesscond-lightregular';
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

}
#inicio .mas-novedades{
  margin-top: 15px
}
#inicio .mas-noticias{
   margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  position: relative
}
#inicio .mas-noticias .forma{
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -70px;
}
#inicio .btn-mas-noticias{
  border-color: #ce3629;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #363636;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
#inicio .btn-mas-noticias:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ce3629
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="inicio">
        <!-- NOVEDADES -->
        <section class="ultimas-novedades">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Últimas novedades</h2>
                <hr>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contenido-novedades">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 sin-padding">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frase">
                      <figure class="snip1208" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="recuadro">
                          <p>“Comunidad, Empresa y Estado” invitación Encuentro de RedEAmérica 25.08</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="date"><span class="day">28</span><span class="month">Oct</span></div><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <a href="#"></a>
                      </figure>                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frase">
                      <figure class="snip1208">
                        <img class="image img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/html/images/desarrolar-economia-video.jpg" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="date"><span class="day">28</span><span class="month">Oct</span></div><img class="icon" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/html/images/svg/video-icono.svg" alt="">
                          <figcaption>
                          <h3>Desarrollar economías regionales</h3>
                        </figcaption>
                        <a href="#"></a>
                      </figure> 

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>


                </div>

           
           </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /NOVEDADES -->
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes mejorar tu pregunta porfavor, poniendo un codigo minimo, completo.

Comment: ahí reduci el código.

Comment: ¿Quieres que halla un boton sobre la imagen de ese tamaño o que la imagen se vuelva el boton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta podría ser una manera, fijate que le agrego a la "div" que ya tenes con clase "frase" la clase hover también.
Ademas agregue unos estilos mínimos al botón en la parte de estilos con la clase "boton_ver".

```js
$(".hover").mouseover(function () {
    if(!$(this).find("button").length)
      $(this).find("a").append("<button type='button' class='boton_ver'>VER VIDEO</button>");
    }
);
  
$(".hover").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find("button").remove();
});
```

```css
/************************************************************************************/
/*********************************ULTIMAS NOVEDADES****************************/
/***********************************************************************************/

#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 {
    font-family: 'stainlesscond-lightregular';
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 236px;
  max-width: 359px;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 307px;

}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .image {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  height: 100%;
  width: 489px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% 0;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 figcaption {
  top: 88%;
  left: 20px;
  right: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 figcaption h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 i {
  background-color: #e41c14;
  top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 25px;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .icon {
  background-color: #e41c14;
  top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 25px;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date .month {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 i {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 52px;
    padding: 20px;

}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 h3,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover img,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover .date {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover i,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover i {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover .icon,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover .icon {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}


#inicio .contenido-novedades figure .recuadro{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 307px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure .recuadro p{
  top: 40%;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'stainlesscond-lightregular';
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

}
#inicio .mas-novedades{
  margin-top: 15px
}
#inicio .mas-noticias{
   margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  position: relative
}
#inicio .mas-noticias .forma{
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -70px;
}
#inicio .btn-mas-noticias{
  border-color: #ce3629;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #363636;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
#inicio .btn-mas-noticias:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ce3629
}

.boton_ver{
  position: absolute;
   background: red;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   width: 120px;
   margin-left: -60px;
   border: none;
   color:white;
   padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="inicio">
        <!-- NOVEDADES -->
        <section class="ultimas-novedades">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Últimas novedades</h2>
                <hr>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contenido-novedades">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 sin-padding">
               
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frase hover">
                      <figure class="snip1208">
                        <img class="image img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/html/images/desarrolar-economia-video.jpg" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="date"><span class="day">28</span><span class="month">Oct</span></div><img class="icon" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/html/images/svg/video-icono.svg" alt="">
                          <figcaption>
                          <h3>Desarrollar economías regionales</h3>
                        </figcaption>
                        <a href="#"></a>
                      </figure> 

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>


                </div>

           
           </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /NOVEDADES -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es otra manera, usando la opacity para tener una transición mas suave cuando se muestra y oculta el botón.

```js
$(".hover").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find("button").css("opacity",1);
});
  
$(".hover").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find("button").css("opacity",0);
});
```

```css
/************************************************************************************/
/*********************************ULTIMAS NOVEDADES****************************/
/***********************************************************************************/

#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 {
    font-family: 'stainlesscond-lightregular';
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 236px;
  max-width: 359px;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 307px;

}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .image {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  height: 100%;
  width: 489px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% 0;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 figcaption {
  top: 88%;
  left: 20px;
  right: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 figcaption h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 i {
  background-color: #e41c14;
  top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 25px;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .icon {
  background-color: #e41c14;
  top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 25px;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .date .month {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 i {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 .icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 52px;
    padding: 20px;

}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 h3,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover img,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover .date,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover .date {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover i,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover i {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208:hover .icon,
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure.snip1208.hover .icon {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}


#inicio .contenido-novedades figure .recuadro{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 307px;
}
#inicio .contenido-novedades figure .recuadro p{
  top: 40%;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'stainlesscond-lightregular';
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

}
#inicio .mas-novedades{
  margin-top: 15px
}
#inicio .mas-noticias{
   margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  position: relative
}
#inicio .mas-noticias .forma{
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -70px;
}
#inicio .btn-mas-noticias{
  border-color: #ce3629;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #363636;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
#inicio .btn-mas-noticias:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ce3629
}

.boton_ver{
  position: absolute;
   background: red;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   width: 120px;
   margin-left: -60px;
   border: none;
   color:white;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   opacity:0;
   transition:.75s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="inicio">
        <!-- NOVEDADES -->
        <section class="ultimas-novedades">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Últimas novedades</h2>
                <hr>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contenido-novedades">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 sin-padding">
               
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frase hover">
                      <figure class="snip1208">
                        <img class="image img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/html/images/desarrolar-economia-video.jpg" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="date"><span class="day">28</span><span class="month">Oct</span></div><img class="icon" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/html/images/svg/video-icono.svg" alt="">
                          <figcaption>
                          <h3>Desarrollar economías regionales</h3>
                        </figcaption>
                        <a href="#"><button type='button' class='boton_ver'>VER VIDEO</button></a>
                      </figure> 

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>


                </div>

           
           </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /NOVEDADES -->
</div>
```

Comment: Buenísimo leonardo muchísimas gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Hola. @ElectricMarian, sí esta es la respuesta que buscas, ayudarías mucho a la comunidad si colocas la pregunta como resuelta, además marcar la mejor respuesta es la mejor forma de agradecer a quien se tomó un momento para ayudarte. Éxitos!